# Errors in command line compilation of Spark WordCount

Tags: scala, apache-spark, word-count

I am trying to compile and run WordCOunt program for Scala using command line without any Maven and sbt support.
The command that I am using to compile the scala program is

**scalac -classpath /spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/ Wordcount.scala**

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

/** Create a RDD of lines from a text file, and keep count of
 *  how often each word appears.
 */
object wordcount {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      // Set up a SparkContext named WordCount that runs locally using
      // all available cores.
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount")
      conf.setMaster("local[*]")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

**MY RESEARCH:**
I have referred to the source code and found that the import statements are in
their required jars.
**For example**
SparkConf is present in package org.apache.spark
which is mentioned in the program.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkConf.scala

**ERRORS I AM FACING :**

> `Wordcount.scala:3: error: **object apache is not a member of package org
>   import org.apache.spark._
>              ^**`
>
> `Wordcount.scala:4: error: **object apache is not a member of package org
>   import org.apache.spark.SparkConf**
>              ^`
>
> `Wordcount.scala:14: error: not found: **type SparkConf
>         val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount")**
>                        ^`
>
> `Wordcount.scala:16: error: not found: **type SparkContext
>         val sc = new SparkContext(conf)**
>                      ^`

four errors found

Comment: The path is correct. I have verified this on my side many times using ls -la

Comment: @RameshMaharjan this is my source code
https://gist.github.com/uutkarshsingh/b6c7694cf09507c3df1ec066093d6687
Is it possible for you to verifiy on your side whether you are getting the same error.
using the appropriate classpath on your side.

Comment: I am following a video tutorial for this and it compiles the code using scala IDE. and executes using IDE itself. Do you want to say that the IDE creates and runs a jar rather than only compilation and running? spark-submit maybe one of the way to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
scalac -classpath "/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*" Wordcount.scala
```

There was a problem with **scalac** command mentioned in your question. If you want to select all jars from a certain directory and put it in classpath then you need to use *** wildcard** character and wrap you path inside double quotes.

please refer: [Including all the jars in a directory within the Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath) for details

Comment: If you can answer it completely it would help others better. @Sukumaar

Comment: @LearneriOS, If it is working for you, then please accept this answer :-)